# Selecting dates and showing results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "reservations" containing columns

id
serviceID
dateCreated
name
email
phone
comments

I want to that user can select date from "dateCreated" (dropdown) and then show the results.
Right now I have this

```
$tbl_name = "reservations";

"$select = SELECT * FROM `".$tbl_name."` LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a `WHERE dateCreated = $date` where $date equals the user provided date.  However, you will want to look at prepared queries to prevent SQL injections from the user input.